# Can Jehovah's Witnesses run for Moderator?

Tags: discussion, election, moderators, jehovah-witnesses

I probably should have asked this a few weeks ago, but didn't think about it.  Can Jehovah's Witnesses run for moderator on secular websites (like this one) or is that something their religion prohibits them from doing?

Comment: This would be a personal decision.

Comment: @Kris I think you have the start of a good answer.

Comment: I thought this was going to be a question from someone else asking if JWs were excluded by some rule!

Comment: Or more generally, is it acceptable for JWs to *participate* in sites that discuss non-JW doctrines?

Comment: I was a little surprised Kris didn't run for mod, FWIW.  But I thought this might be the reason.

Comment: @RayButterworth  JWs  endeavor to understand all denominational points of view. This site is designed to provide clear answers to specific questions. I have found it helpful to me in my conversations with non JWs. Very often I find that I have a better grasp on the official teaching of a particular group, thanks to this site, than the person professing to belong to said denomination.

Comment: As Kris said, this is a personal decision. There are a few duties of moderators that can present problems for Jehovah's Witnesses. For one, it would mean being responsible for the moderation of content posted by apostates or to interact with ones who have been disfellowshipped. We strive to have minimal contact with these ones to the best of our ability.

Comment: This question might actually be more on-topic for the main site. Though I can also see how asking on meta allows the community to discuss the duties of moderators.

Comment: @4castle the rule for stackoverflow, at least, was you don't talk about stackoverflow (until they made meta)

Comment: @Kris, the reason I asked is because many years ago, when I worked at a summer day camp, a few of the children were JWs, and weren't allowed to take part in one of the regular activities simply because it was held indoors in a meeting room of a church building.  But perhaps that was because they were children.  I'm also thinking of [(2Corinthians 6:17)](https://www.jw.org/en/library/bible/nwt/books/2-corinthians/6/#v47006017) and separating oneself from non-believers.